# -XX:HeapDumpPath file output to a remote location

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

Good day.
I have a JAVA application that writes a heapdump when an OutOfMemoryError ocurrs, the location of the heapdump is inconvenient and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can configure the automatic heapdump to place the dump file in a remote location other than the original server.
I know that for jmap there is an option that looks like this:

`jmap [ option ] [server-id@]remote-hostname-or-IP`

(see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html)

But what I'm trying to do is directly on the VM options:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=server-ip/server-directory
```

Comment: `HeapDumpPath` specifies a file name or a directory. That's it. This can be a remote location, only if the path points to some kind of network file system (NFS, CIFS, etc.)

Comment: Right I see what you mean. Going to try with an smb thanks